# Remove files from cvs with a certain pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cvs

I have a directory structure that has many files. The whole structure along with the files is checked into cvs. I want to remove  .txt files from it.

I guess cvs remove works in 3 steps:
1) rm command
2) cvs remove
3) cvs commit

How can I ahead in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you gave are correct, but they don't need to be done individually. They can be combined.

If you *really* want to remove all `*.txt` files and not just a specific set of files, you can do this from the top level of your checked out project:

```
find -name '*.txt' | xargs cvs rm -f
cvs commit
```

The `find` will find all `*.txt` files in your directory and `xargs` will flatten out this list and put it at the end of the `cvs rm -f`. The `-f` flag combines step one and two from your list.

The files are now scheduled for deletion and you can delete them using the `commit`.

Answer (score -1):

In CVS you can *remove* things two ways:

- By using `cvs rm`
- By removing `,v` files from the repo.

The first method is a thin abstraction on top of *moving* the `,v` files into a "magic" directory and remembering *when* this operation happened.

You should *most definitely* use the first method as it preserves the historical repository (i.e. checking out a snapshot as of past date would be identical to what it would've been before you removed the files). In the latter case, the files will be gone even for last releases.